# Editor does not load if textarea id has special character

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-6

TinyMCE editor does not get rendered if the textarea element's id contains special characters. For instance, one of my textarea to which I want to associate the TinyMCE editor has an id something like "DESCRLONF$0". Editor does not get rendered for this field.

Editor loads if I remove $ from the id attribute value. But i would expect the editor to load irrespective of what the id attribute value contains. Many of my textarea field id contains $ at a minimum. Anyone tried and faced the same?